# Joining the same table twice with different values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I'm trying to replace the value of "transfers.pickup_areas_group_id" and "transfers.drop_areas_group_id" with the values from the table "areas_group", using IDs

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT 
transfers.id AS transfer_id, 
transfers.name AS transfer_name,  
transfers.pickup_areas_group_id AS transfer_pickup_areas_group_id,
transfers.drop_areas_group_id AS transfer_drop_areas_group_id, 
transfers_pricing.vehicle_id AS vehicle_id, 
transfers_pricing.date_start AS date_start, 
transfers_pricing.date_end AS date_end, 
transfers_pricing.price AS price 
FROM transfers
INNER JOIN transfers_pricing ON transfers_pricing.transfer_id = transfers.id
```

I tried an extra INNER JOIN to replace the first value "transfers.pickup_areas_group_id", but I couldn't find a way to replace the second one "transfers.drop_areas_group_id"

I tried this query:

```
SELECT 
transfers.id AS transfer_id, 
transfers.name AS transfer_name,  
transfers.pickup_areas_group_id AS transfer_pickup_areas_group_id,
areas_group.area_id AS pickup_area_ids,
transfers.drop_areas_group_id AS transfer_drop_areas_group_id, 
transfers_pricing.vehicle_id AS vehicle_id, 
transfers_pricing.date_start AS date_start, 
transfers_pricing.date_end AS date_end, 
transfers_pricing.price AS price 
FROM transfers
INNER JOIN transfers_pricing ON transfers_pricing.transfer_id = transfers.id
INNER JOIN areas_group ON areas_group.id = transfers.pickup_areas_group_id
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need another join on `areas_group`; to disambiguate the two references to the same table, you need to use a table alias.

Actually, it is a good practice to use table aliases for all tables that come into play in the query: this makes the query shorter to read and write.

```
SELECT 
    t.id AS transfer_id, 
    t.name AS transfer_name,  
    t.pickup_areas_group_id AS transfer_pickup_areas_group_id,
    ag1.area_id AS pickup_area_ids,
    t.drop_areas_group_id AS transfer_drop_areas_group_id, 
    ag2.area_id AS drop_area_ids
    tp.vehicle_id AS vehicle_id, 
    tp.date_start AS date_start, 
    tp.date_end AS date_end, 
    tp.price AS price 
FROM transfers t
INNER JOIN transfers_pricing tp ON tp.transfer_id = t.id
INNER JOIN areas_group ag1 ON ag1.id = t.pickup_areas_group_id
INNER JOIN areas_group ag2 ON ag2.id = t.drop_areas_group_id
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I needed! thank you so much dear.